# how to pass different variables for list to json object

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
with open ("xyz.json") as f:
    json_load=json.load(f)
    lis=["response.result.Potentials","response.result.Potentials.row",...........]
```

How to pass from list `l1` to JSON object (getting the variable from list `l1` and passing the variables JSON object).(IF we add anything to list and calls it should print json values).

```
print(data[l1[0]])
```

i want print from list `l1` i.e `print(data[response][result][Potentials])`

```
print(data[l1[1]])
```

i.e `print(data[response][result][Potentials][row])` in JSON format:

```
 {"response":
        {"result":
            {"Potentials":
                {"row":
                    [
                    {"no":"1","FL":
                        {"content":"523836000004148171","val":"POTENTIALID"}
                    },
                    {"no":"2","FL":
                        {"content":"523836000004924051","val":"POTENTIALID"}
                    },
                    {"no":"3","FL":
                        [
                        {"content":"523836000005318448","val":"POTENTIALID"},
                        {"content":"694275295","val":"Campaign Confirmation Number"}
                        ]
                    },
                    {"no":"4","FL":
                        [
                        {"content":"523836000005318662","val":"POTENTIALID"},
                        {"content":"729545274","val":"Campaign Confirmation Number"}
                        ]
                    },
                    {"no":"5","FL":
                        [
                        {"content":"523836000005318663","val":"POTENTIALID"},
                        {"content":"903187021","val":"Campaign Confirmation Number"}
                        ]
                    },
                    {"no":"6","FL":
                        {"content":"523836000005322387","val":"POTENTIALID"}
                    },
                    {"no":"7","FL":
                        [
                        {"content":"523836000005332558","val":"POTENTIALID"},
                        {"content":"729416761","val":"Campaign Confirmation Number"}
                        ]
                    }
                    ]
                }
            },
        "uri":"/crm/private/json/Potentials/getSearchRecords"}
    }
```

Comment: How your `data` looks like?

Comment: Hi P.R,,Yes, list l1 is another variable (just passing dynamically to json object)

Comment: i.e print(data[name][id]) variable should come from list l1[0]

Comment: {"name":{"id": "12354","emp":{"gener": "m"}}},
{"name":{"id": "12453","emp":{"gener": "m"}}}
{"name":{"id": "126763","emp":{"gener": "m"}}}.....................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is a `dict` type object so, you can also do it like,

```
 data.get(lis[0])
```

In this case you can do it like this:

```
for item in lis:
    temp_data = json_load
    for attr in item.split('.'):
        value = temp_data.get(attr)
        temp_data = value
    print value
```

Comment: i am getting error  lis=["response.result.Potentials.row.FL","response.result.Potentials.row"]value = temp_data.get(attr)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: row's value is list. not dictionary so it has no 'get' attribute. you can access it like `data['response']['result']['Potentials']['row'][0]['FL']`.

Answer (score 0):

To create a json output given a python object, you can simply use `json.dumps(var)` This will work with any combination of Python primitives, lists and dictionaries.

```
with open ("xyz.json") as f:
    data=json.load(f) 

l1=[name.id,name.id.gener]

#this depends on structure of json
data[l1] =l1 #if dict
data.append(l1) #if list of lists
data.extend(l1) #if flat list

with open ("xyz.json", 'w') as wb:
    wb.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: print(data[name][id]) variable should come from list l1[0]

Comment: can you post your json data?  Still not 100% on if you are trying to output to file or read from file.

Comment: {"name":{"id": "12354","emp":{"gener": "m"}}},
{"name":{"id": "12453","emp":{"gener": "m"}}}
{"name":{"id": "126763","emp":{"gener": "m"}}}.....................